# Training and Validation Loss saturates at a value and does not decrease any further

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a network for detecting 68 landmarks (x, y) on face. The training and validation images are 320x320x3 normalized between -0.5 and 0.5. My labels are 136 logits, each between 0 to 1.0 corresponding to X->(0, 320); Y->(0, 320). The loss function is keras "root_mean_square". Number of images in training dataset is about 5k. While training, my training and validation loss starts at about 6.0 and decreases to about 0.0022 in 100 iterations but then seems to be saturated at that level and does not go any lower. I have tried up to 2000 iterations. Looking at the output, it seems like the network learns to output 68 points in the shape of a face at the center of frame irrespective of where the really is.

I am using generator for getting the data and using `sklearn.utils.shuffle()` to make sure my data is shuffled properly.

Some posts suggested that the network could be overfitting because it is so complex for such a simple problem, so I have tried both a very simple network with about 10 layers and complex network of about 20 layers and my result is still the same. My current network is shown below, I have used 2 skip connections, 3 dropouts, and l2 regularizer to make sure that my network does not overfit. Underfitting should not be an issue because I have tried training my network for up to 2000 iterations.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```html
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 320, 320, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 320, 320, 3)  228         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 320, 320, 3)  12          conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 320, 320, 3)  0           batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 160, 160, 3)  0           activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 160, 160, 8)  608         max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 160, 160, 8)  32          conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)       (None, 160, 160, 8)  0           batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 80, 80, 8)    0           activation_2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 80, 80, 16)   1168        max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 80, 80, 16)   2320        conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNor (None, 80, 80, 16)   64          conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)       (None, 80, 80, 16)   0           batch_normalization_3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 40, 40, 16)   0           activation_3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 40, 40, 32)   4640        max_pooling2d_4[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 40, 40, 32)   9248        conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 40, 40, 32)   9248        conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNor (None, 40, 40, 32)   128         conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)       (None, 40, 40, 32)   0           batch_normalization_4[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 20, 20, 32)   0           activation_4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 20, 20, 32)   0           max_pooling2d_6[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 20, 20, 64)   18496       dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 20, 20, 64)   36928       conv2d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 20, 20, 16)   0           conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 20, 20, 64)   36928       conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 20, 20, 80)   0           max_pooling2d_3[0][0]            
                                                                 conv2d_10[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNor (None, 20, 20, 80)   320         concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)       (None, 20, 20, 80)   0           batch_normalization_5[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 10, 10, 80)   0           activation_5[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 10, 10, 80)   0           max_pooling2d_7[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, 10, 10, 128)  92288       dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              (None, 10, 10, 128)  147584      conv2d_11[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 10, 10, 32)   0           conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              (None, 10, 10, 128)  147584      conv2d_12[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 10, 10, 160)  0           max_pooling2d_5[0][0]            
                                                                 conv2d_13[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNor (None, 10, 10, 160)  640         concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)       (None, 10, 10, 160)  0           batch_normalization_6[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_8 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 5, 5, 160)    0           activation_6[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 5, 5, 160)    0           max_pooling2d_8[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)             (None, 4000)         0           dropout_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 1024)         4097024     flatten_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 136)          139400      dense_3[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 4,744,888
Trainable params: 4,744,290
Non-trainable params: 598
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```